# Java library providing make-like functionality

Tags: library, java

I'm searching a library, which provides same, or similar,
functionality as `make`:

- definition of rules:

  - input file(s) - names / wildcard / regex pattern,
  - output file(s) - names / wildcard / regex pattern,
  - command (instance implementing some `Runnable`-like interface),
- determine outdated outputs based on  (timestamp) changes to input files.

EDIT:

The library must be licensed under license, which is compatible with Apache 2.0.

Comment: You probaby know this: since the late 1990s, [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) has been available. From the [faq](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html): *"What is Apache Ant?  A: Ant is a Java-based build tool. In theory, it is kind of like Make, without Make's wrinkles and with the full portability of pure Java code."*

Comment: Are you asking for a Java build system? You have a choice of many. *Apache Ant* is the oldest. Most popular nowadays is *Apache Maven* and *Apache Gradle*.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Make in Java](http://jmk.sourceforge.net/edu/neu/ccs/jmk/index.html), which without taking too much time to look, seems like a Java make implementation (or something similar to make). It is LGPL licensed.

Comment: Sounds interesting,.. but, **LGPL library can not be used in Apache 2.0** project,... And, I don't want my project to put restrictions on users / developers,..